# How to execute code after a spawned, detached, child exits from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, child-process

My objective is to have some code execute after a detached, unreferenced, child process is spawned from a NodeJS app.  Here is the code that I have:

```
var child_options = {
      cwd : prj
    , env : {
                PATH: cmd_directory
            }
    , detatched : true
    , stdio     : 'ignore'
};

//Spawn a child process with myapp with the options and command line params
child = spawn('myapp', params_array, child_options, function(err, stdout, stderr){

    if (err) {
        console.log("\t\tProblem executing myapp =>\n\t\t" + err);
    } else {
        console.log("\t\tLaunched myapp successfully!")
    }

});

//Handle the child processes exiting.  Maybe send an email?
child.on('exit', function(data) {

    fs.writeFile(path.resolve("/Users/me/Desktop/myapp-child.log"), "Finished with child process!");

});

//Let the child process run in its own session without parent
child.unref();
```

So the function inside the `exit` handler does not seem to get executed when the child process finishes.  Is there any way at all to have code execute after the child process exits even when it's detached and when calling the `.unref()` method?

Note that if I change the `'stdio'` key value in the `child_options` object from `'ignore'` to `'inherit'` then the `exit` handler does execute.

Any ideas?

UPDATE PART 1

---

So, I still can not figure this one out.  I went back to the NodeJS docs on spawn, and noticed the example about spawning "long-running processes".  In one example, they redirect the child process' output to files instead of just using `'ignore'` for the `'stdio'` option.  So I changed the `'stdio'` key within the `child_options` object as in the following, but alas I am still not able to execute the code within the `'close'` or `'exit'` event:

```
var out_log = fs.openSync(path.resolve(os.tmpdir(), "stdout.log"), 'a'),
    err_log = fs.openSync(path.resolve(os.tmpdir(), "stderr.log"), 'a');

var child_options = {
      cwd : prj
    , env : {
                PATH: cmd_directory
            }
    , detatched : true
    , stdio     : ['ignore', out_log, err_log]
};
```

So, the stdout.log file does get the stdout from the child process—so I know it gets redirected.  However, the code in the `close` or `exit` event still does not execute.  Then I thought I would be able to detect when the writing to the `out_log` file was finished, in which case I would be able to execute code at that point.  However, I cannot figure out how to do that.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener to 'close' event, e.g. replace 'exit' with 'close'. It worked on my side even with 'ignore' stdio. Also, input parameter in callback is exit code number or null.

According to nodejs documentation difference between exit and close events:

> The 'close' event is emitted when the stdio streams of a child process
>   have been closed. This is distinct from the 'exit' event, since
>   multiple processes might share the same stdio streams.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed it to `'close'` and still no luck on the writing of the log file to my Desktop.  I thought it might have to do with some permissions issue for writing to the Desktop, but I doubt it since if I use `'inherit'` for the child process the file does get written to the desktop.  Regarding your statement about "input parameter", are you referring to the `data` parameter?  I'll try removing that.

Comment: Yes, I meant `data` parameter, but it doesn't important, just notice. Did you checked, that process is launched if you pass 'ignore' parameter? I had similar situations and the issue was in waiting for input stream by a child process and child process didn't do anything.

Comment: I know for certain, by examining the "Activity Monitor" application on macOS that the child process does, in fact, launch when I use the `'ignore'` value for the `'stdio'` key.  I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for late response. My statement wasn't clear. I mean, I had the situations, when the process is launched (in my case web server), but it didn't listen port, so I couldn't send any query. I think, the reason was in waiting for input from stdin by launched web server. I removed processing input in web server and all magically worked with 'ignore' value for 'stdio' key. Please, clarify, is callback on 'exit' event triggered with 'ignore' value for 'stdio' or not?

Comment: The child process, I'm launching is not a web server.  It does some transcoding of files then finishes.  It does seem, though, that the command I call to launch itself spawns another process.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Still was unable to understand the issue here.  I updated my answer to reflect my latest changes and findings.  Thanks.

Comment: Spawning another child can produce waiting for closing stdio, since multiple processes can share it. Did you that spawned process and children of spawned pocess were finished? Am I understand your situation correctly: you spawn the process by node, see that process is launched and write something to output, spawned process is killed, you see that there isn't process with spawned pid, but exit and close events aren't triggered, yes?

Comment: Yes, this is basically it.  Except that I do get a PID when calling child_process.spawn()

Comment: Were there child processes of spawned process by node.js after finishing process itself?

Comment: Yes, the child process spawned by my app code itself spawns a child process — at least that's what I see in the Activity Monitor.  Could that be the problem?  It appears that the secondary child that is spawned does the "grunt work" and is where the stdout is coming from.  Thoughts?

Comment: If child processes aren't finished, the process can't close stdin, stdout, stderr streams. Maybe child process uses some stream, that's why node process doesn't emit close event and you observe weird behavior. I'm sorry, but I don't know a solution for your problem